# Keeping uncooked Christmas pudding mix

Tags: storage-lifetime, steamed-pudding

I have a Christmas pudding mix recipe intended for a 1.5 l pudding basin, but I need to slow cook it in a 1.2 l, so I'll have a little left over to make one or two miniature puddings. They won't fit in the slow cooker at the same time as the big pudding so I'll need to keep them uncooked. The recipe consists of a large amount of fruit bound together with flour, breadcrumbs, sugar, suet and 2 eggs. The eggs are why I can't just scale down a little - plus I want the mini pudding(s).

I assume the uncooked mix will keep in a fridge, but for how long? The main pudding will take all day to cook and ideally I'd cook the other pudding the next day.

I assume it will be safe given that I'm talking about 24 hours in the fridge - correct me if I'm wrong - but will it keep nicely? Should it be mixed again after keeping it in the fridge? Another assumption is that it will be more forgiving than a typical cake mix given that there's more fruit than anything else.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but all eggs are not the same size. It seems very unlikely that you couldn't scale the rest of the ingredients to 1.2 liters and use two eggs.

Comment: @MaxW it probably specifies in the recipe but I didn't have it in front of me. Also I'd quite like the mini ones for myself!  I haven't made this recipe before so don't have a feel for how forgiving it is. My larger pudding basin will be in use holding another Christmas pudding, otherwise it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Not sure if this would work for you, but, might it make sense to cook the mini ones first?  They shouldn't take nearly as long as the larger pudding, so if there is still time the same day for the larger pudding (should be, I think), the amount of time the mix will sit will be minimal - hour or two rather than a day.  Or even cook them stove-top instead of in a slow cooker, as was traditional.  I don't know how long the mix can sit or with what limitations, but it may be possible to avoid the *need* for it to sit that long.

Comment: @Megha cooking the mini ones on the stove might work. I wanted to slow cook them as its so much more forgiving and I don't know how much to adjust this particular recipe for the stove. If I found a recipe with timings for mini and full size puddings I could use the ratio. Cooking full size puddings on the stove is a pain - steam everywhere (or draughts) and continual checking of the water. Slow cooking is so much simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I tried it, or something similar.  I made a batch of mini puddings, but only 4 out of 8 individual pudding basins fitted in the slow cooker at a time.  So the second half of the batch went in the fridge for 7 hours while I cooked the first 4.  The second lot were cooked overnight, starting from fridge cold, but with the water topped up to as deep as I could go, straight from a boiling kettle.  The two batches are indistinguishable -- I've sampled both.

What didn't work so well were the few I made by microwaving in silicone muffin tins after I ran out of pudding basins before using all the mix.