# How long will uncooked Christmas pudding mixture last?

Tags: food-safety, storage

Is it safe to keep uncooked Christmas pudding mixture for a week before cooking? This is for a Christmas pudding with stout and brandy.

Comment: [I asked something similar a few years ago](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/85720/20413), but never got an answer beyond my own success using it within 24 hours (kept in the fridge).

Comment: Note that even in the richest recipes there's far too little alcohol to have much of a a preserving effect, no more than a few percent, (less than 2% in the one that's currently in my slow cooker)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will now ditch the uncooked mixture. Not risking a bout of food poisoning over Christmas!

Comment: The sad thing is it's probably fine in the fridge for most if not all of that time. But it's one thing to chance it for yourself (I'd turn it into mini ones for me) and another for guests.

Answer (score 1):

Nov 20th is the traditional day to make xmas pudding and many recipes call for the batter to 'rest' for up to a week anyway.

Comment: I've never seen a recipe that rests the complete uncooked mix, so it's far from common. Soaking the dried fruit is fairly common, and of course once cooked it keeps for weeks. But the surface of the raw mix is likely to have cut up fruit, damp flour/breadcrumbs, and other things known to spoil within a few days. So a recipe that does have a resting step might well have something special about it that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: As per Gary Rhodes, who knew a thing or two: "Allow pudding mix to chill for at least 24 hours, and preferably for 1 week"

Comment: He may well do (one recipe not "many"), but without the actual recipes, who knows whether it's remotely relevant to this question? At he very least we'd need to know the proportions and storage conditions/preparations

Comment: My mother said 5th November was the traditional day to make christmas puddings, while the menfolk where out celebrating catholic burning day.

Comment: @User65535 I looked it up and "Stir-up Sunday" is the last Sunday before the Advent. My family would have been the catholics being burnt but I couldnt tell you when the Advent actually is but I gather it changes every year so not necessarily Nov 20th as I originally said, but also probably not as early as 5th.